# Simple Calender Script with jquery - How to calculate days of the last month?

Tags: javascript, jquery, calendar

For a project I need a very simple calendar. So I got some code from the internet and modified it.

My current Code and what I did you can see on http://jsfiddle.net/baa2tqdo/1/. To summarize here the important parts of the code.

My HTML Code:

```
<html>
<!-- ... -->
<div id="container">
    <div class="box">
        <!-- Calendar -->
        <div class="calendar"></div>
    </div>
</div>
<!-- ... -->
</html>
```

And my JavaScript Code

```
var calendar = function () {

    var date = new Date();

    createCalendarHead(date);
    createCalendar(date);

    // month back
    $('.back').click(function () {
        date = decreaseMonth(date);
        $('.calendar-body').empty();
        createCalendar(date);
    });

    // year back
    $('.back-year').click(function () {
        date.setYear(date.getYear() - 1);
        $('.calendar-body').empty();
        createCalendar(date);
    });

    // month forward
    $('.forward').click(function () {
        date = increaseMonth(date);
        $('.calendar-body').empty();
        createCalendar(date);
    });

    // year forward
    $('.forward-year').click(function () {
        date.setYear(date.getYear() + 1);
        $('.calendar-body').empty();
        createCalendar(date);
    });

    // Current
    $('.current').click(function () {
        date = new Date();
        $('.calendar-body').empty();
        createCalendar(date);
    });
};

function increaseMonth(d) {
    if (d.getMonth() == 11) {
        d.setMonth(0);
        d.setYear(d.getYear() + 1);
    } else {
        d.setMonth(d.getMonth() + 1);
    }

    return d;
}

function decreaseMonth(d) {
    if (d.getMonth() == 0) {
        d.setMonth(11);
        d.setYear(d.getYear() - 1);
    } else {
        d.setMonth(d.getMonth() - 1);
    }

    return d;
}

function getLastMonth(d) {
    if (d.getMonth() == 0) {
        return 11
    } else {
        return d.getMonth() - 1;
    }
}

function replaceAll(find, replace, str) {
    var tempStr = str.replace(find, replace);
    if (tempStr.contains(find)) {
        return replaceAll(find, replace, tempStr);
    }
    return tempStr;
}

function createCalendarHead(d) {

    var months = ['Januar', 'Februar', 'März', 'April', 'Mai', 'Juni', 'Juli', 'August', 'September', 'Oktober', 'November', 'Dezember'];
    var days = ['Montag', 'Dienstag', 'Mittwoch', 'Donnerstag', 'Freitag', 'Samstag', 'Sonntag'];

    // add head and body for calendar
    $('.calendar')
        .append('<div class="calendar-nav">')
        .append('<div class="calendar-head">')
        .append('<div class="calendar-body">');

    $('.calendar-nav')
        .append('<div class="back-forward">')
        .append('<div class="current-date">' + months[d.getMonth()] + ' ' + (d.getYear() <= 200 ? d.getYear() + 1900 : d.getYear()) + '</div>');

    $('.back-forward')
        .append('<input type="button" class="button back-year" value="<<"/>')
        .append('<input type="button" class="button back" value="<"/>')
        .append('<input type="button" class="button current" value="today"/>')
        .append('<input type="button" class="button forward" value=">"/>')
        .append('<input type="button" class="button forward-year" value=">>"/>');

    // fill head with days
    for (var c = 0; c < days.length; c++) {
        $('.calendar-head')
            .append('<div class="days">' + days[c] + '</div>');
    }
}

function createCalendar(date) {

    var months = ['Januar', 'Februar', 'März', 'April', 'Mai', 'Juni', 'Juli', 'August', 'September', 'Oktober', 'November', 'Dezember'];
    var days_in_month = [31, 28, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31];

    var d = date;
    var day = d.getDate();
    var month = d.getMonth();
    var year = d.getYear();

    year <= 200 ? year += 1900 : year;

    // leap year?
    year % 4 == 0 && year != 1900 ? days_in_month[1] = 29 : days_in_month;

    // days in current month
    var total = days_in_month[month];

    // calculate days of last month
    var DatumMonat = d;
    DatumMonat.setDate(1);
    var ErsterTag = DatumMonat.getDay();

    // add days of last month
    for (var i = 1; i < ErsterTag; i++) {
        $('.calendar-body').append('<div class="day-box last-month">' +
        (days_in_month[getLastMonth(d)] - ((ErsterTag - 1) - i)) +
        '</div>');
    }

    var $tagDatum;
    var $classTagDatum;

    for (i = 1; i <= total; i++) {

        // create current date as string
        $tagDatum = (i < 10 ? '0' + i : i) + '' + (month + 1) + '' + year;
        $classTagDatum = "." + $tagDatum;

        $('.calendar-body ').append('<div class="day-box ' + $tagDatum + '">');

        if (day == i) $($classTagDatum).append('<div class="tag today">' + i + '</div>');
        else $($classTagDatum).append('<div class="tag">' + i + '</div>')
    }

    $('.current-date')
        .empty()
        .text(months[month] + ' ' + (year <= 200 ? year + 1900 : year));
}
```

But the days of the last month are not displayed correctly (except for the current month) and I can not find my mistake. My second problem is to display the month and year correctly. After changing the year two times it does not work anymore. I hope someone can help me to solve my problems or at least give me some tips. Thank you in advance.

Comment: just a FYI. you could use this http://fullcalendar.io/ or http://glad.github.io/glDatePicker/

Comment: I think you're doing a bit of reinventing here. You're going to go through this process of creation, debugging, and testing until you're happy with it. Unless it's for a required school credit, I would abandon your current work and look at fullcalendar.io which on the download page has this quote "Includes a basic stylesheet, the Google Calendar extension, and the necessary Moment and jQuery files." I share that quote because of its reference to moment.js, a time manipulation library that will remove all of the fuss from logical problems you will continue to encounter implementing a solution.

Comment: Btw, fullcalendar has its own Stack Overflow tag

Comment: @Pointy, 1900 was not and 2100 will not be a leap year because they are evenly divisible by 100, but 2000 *was* was a leap year because although 2000 is evenly divisible by 100, it is also evenly divisible by 400. 1600 and 2400 are the same.

Comment: @Roamer-1888 oh yea :) I guess it's been a while since I actually had to write code like that!

Comment: @ThisClark, you are right but it is for an uni project. So its not allowed to use existing code excluding jQuery, sorry. -.-

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use magic numbers like 0, 30, 11. It will complicate the code.

Pass selected date of calendar to your function

Set date to 1 to the passed variable (set month to 1 for previous year)

Add day -1 to new date.

Set passed date to new date.

Use same approach for next month or year selection. Use date functions to change the date rather than setting numbers of month ir year. This will handle leap year and different month days

Answer (score 0):

Use date.getFullYear(). getYear() is deprecated.